# Wanna customize Wordpress theme by adding an image section in header but error: syntax error, unexpected 'action' (T_STRING)

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax, themes

**#In Theme Function** 
//one file
//Add image in heading

```
function lwp_header_callout($wp_customize){
    $wp_customize->add_setting('lwp-header-callout-image');
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Cropped_Image_Control($wp_customize,'lwp-header-callout-image-control',array(
    'label'=>'Image',
    'section'=>'lwp-header-callout-section',
    'setting'=>'lwp-header-callout-image',
    'width'=>1190,
    'height'=>129)));
}
add action('customize_register','lwp_header_callout');
```

*//End image in heading*

**#In Theme header** 
*//second file
//start header*

```
<div class="nicdark_grid_12" >

            <div class="nicdark_section nicdark_height_80"></div>
            <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_template_directory_uri('lwp-footer-callout-image'))?>">
<div class="nicdark_section nicdark_height_80"></div>
```

*//End header*

**In Theme style section**

**//third file
// Start Header callout section**

```
.Header-callout-image{
    width:100%,
    }
```

**//End**

Comment: You have a typo. `add action(...)` should be `add_action(...)`. You're missing `_`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct `add action('customize_register','lwp_header_callout');` to

```
add_action('customize_register','lwp_header_callout');
```

Comment: We tend not to answer typo questions since they are rarely helpful for others. We usually just post a comment about it and then close the question as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get image using [get_theme_mod()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/), so the function would be like shown:

```
<img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url(get_theme_mod('lwp-footer-callout-image'))?>">
```

Comment: That won't help with the error message the OP is getting.

Comment: That's right, sorry about that, the answer above me got the error :)